# Apache hive create table with ASCII value as delimiter

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I need to load a datafile into hive internal table. The file has character Æ as delimeter.

I tried giving ASCII value as delimiter -

```
create table dbname.tablename (
col1 Varchar(500),
col2 VARCHAR(500),
col3 VARCHAR(500)
)
row format delimited fields terminated by '\306';
```

create table is success, But data is not loading correctly.

I have tried Dec(198), Hex(C6) and Oct(306) ASCII values for character Æ-

Sample Data :

```
col1DataÆcol2DataÆcol3Data
```

load statment :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/path/sample.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: Post sample data from the file.

Comment: @VK_217 I have added sample data

Answer (score 0):

`'\198'` should work.You also need to add the load statement for the data to be loaded.See [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-DMLOperations) for load statement example.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/path/sample.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE TABLE_NAME;
```